# Subclassed Content Type in Site Template / Document Library Template

Tags: 2007, document-library, content-type, site-template

What I'm trying to do is effectively have a document library content type defined at the site collection level, I then want sites within the Site Collection to be able to edit the defaults for the fields on a site by site basis.

The only way I've been able to remotely get this to work is to create a base content type at the site collection level (without fields that defaults are required), then a new inheriting content type at the site level with the added columns and defaults set. Now this works fine for the site I'm creating and even kind of works if I template the site and create a new site from the template in so much as it all seems to work, except on the site created with the template the custom content type isn't created, instead it just has the columns added and not the custom type so I can't change the defaults at the newly created site level.

The client basically wants a content type that will be applied to all document libraries in a Site Collection, but that they can edit at a site level to affect all document libraries in the site and then further customize on specific document libraries if required. They also want to be able to change the 'original' content type if required and have those changes cascaded down to all sites and sub sites etc.

Anyone got any advice on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled "Allow management of Content Types" on the subsite libraries? (List settings -> Advanced settings).  That should get you what you need.

BTW the practice of creating a base content type used throughout the enterprise is a great practice, and it bugs me that more organizations don't understand this.

And as far as the ability to edit a base content type and have it cascade through to its descendents, you won't be able to do that on 2007.  The Content Type Hub (available starting in 2010) would go a long way towards simplifying this task, so if your organization is looking for justfication to upgrade to 2010 or 2013, add this to the list.

Comment: Thanks for response.I have enabled ‘allow management of content types’ on the subsite libraries,the subsites do not allow the customisation of the base document type at the site level which will then cascade to doc libraries in subsite
What I want is
Base Type: title,name,etc,category,keywords
At a subsite level I want the same as the base type but with different defaults specified for subject category and subject keywords but then at a document library level to be able to again change potentially what the defaults are I need to be able to package this up into a team site template to be reused